# Only every other link is working properly in Bootstrap 5 popovers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, popover, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

Hi guys this is my first question here and i've done some thorough research on this problem. I honestly feel a bit stupid at this point. So here's the issue:

I am using Bootstrap 5 on a project and have a popover to show sharing links to social media. Almost everything works like a charm, but when i want to display more than one link (< a href = "somelink" >) within a popover, only one works properly. If i add a third link then the first and the third link will work, but not the second one. If i add even more links, only every other works.

And this is where it gets really weird: If i close the popover and re-open it, the links that work have switched! So this time the first and the third link don't work, but the second one does. And this behaviour can be reproduced. So if i close the popover again on the next opening the links that work switched back to the prior state. it just toggles it. And in the chrome webdevtools the href is just vanishing from the code and reappearing again with no errors whatsoever in the console area.

Maybe one of you guys can help me with this. Here's the code thats used for the popover:

```html
    <button class="btn btn-icon sug_share" type="button" value="social_share" active data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-content="'.$popUpContent.'" role="button">
    <i class="bi bi-share-fill"></i> Teilen</button>
```

You may have noticed the PHP variable there filling up the data-bs-content attribute. It contains the following:

```html
    <span>
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=pathtopage' target='_blank'><i class='bi bi-facebook'></i> Facebook</a>
    </span> | 
    <span>
    <a href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=pathtopage' target='_blank'><i class='bi bi-twitter'></i> Twitter</a>
    </span> | 
    <span>
    <a href='https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=pathtopage' target='_blank'><i class='bi bi-linkedin'></i> LinkedIn</a>
    </span>
```

I am telling bootstrap which popovers to open by using the standard JS-method offered in their website:

```js
    var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
    var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
    })
```

I am far from being perfect at JS, especially when it comes to handing variables from PHP to JS, thats why i choose this method of creating the popovers. But i really am at my whits end right now. Hopefully some of you can help me.

Thank you in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the PHP variable for `data-bs-content`? Can you create an example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but no, it sadly doesnt work if i don't use the PHP variable. Ive uploaded a stripped down version of the part thats creating the issue here: [link](https://jenskaesbauer.000webhostapp.com/bootstrap_test.html)

By clicking on the share icon, you can see the "feature" in action. ;)

Comment: Instead of linking to external site, use stack snippets or codeply to create a minimal example. Also the demo is using the font tag which is no longer supported.